# Apache Redirect setting https to http and matching & not matching

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I am confusing about redirect setting by apache.  It looks simple but I can’t figure out…

**Under http access**

```
 if carts/ and events/* need to redirect to https
```

I am adding this setting in sites-enabled/default-http.conf

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/carts/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/events/*
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</ifModule>
```

**Under https access**

```
 if not carts/ and events/* need to redirect to http
```

I am adding this setting in sites-enabled/default-https.conf

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/carts/) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/events/*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</ifModule>
```

**The problem is this**

http is working well however https does not work.
https://test.com/test should redirect to http://test.com/test

Comment: I have add an issue :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all to avoid restart of Apache enable .htaccess (if not enabled already) then use these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(carts|events)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(carts|events)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```

Test this in a new browser to avoid old browser cache. And preferable test in chrome dev tool to see what redirects you're getting.